# Coffeescript firing only on page reloads - Rails 4

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, forms, coffeescript

I'm developing a marketplace app. When a seller creates a listing, they enter their bank account info for payment transfer. When the seller submits listing, coffeescript gets a token from Stripe. I got this to work when I developed the first version of the app. Then i added more features and now for some reason, here is what happens...

- seller submits listing form. coffee script does not fire. i hit back button and submit form again. coffeescript fires.

Here is my log during the first submit - see last row:

```
Parameters: {"utf8"=>"√", "authenticity_token"=>"S4hE7Ku7XsOII6cxTWa+Hoc7+O7bk
Whgk/zo3CODyBw=", "listing"=>{"name"=>"test johntemp", "description"=>"ssfdfsd",
"price"=>"22", "category"=>"Necklaces", "inventory"=>"3", "image"=>#<ActionDisp
atch::Http::UploadedFile:0x3fb15a0 @tempfile=#<Tempfile:C:/Users/amoosa/AppData/
Local/Temp/RackMultipart20140809-3840-4pno42>, @original_filename="gold-chain-br
acelet.jpg", @content_type="image/jpeg", @headers="Content-Disposition: form-dat
a; name=\"listing[image]\"; filename=\"gold-chain-bracelet.jpg\"\r\nContent-Type
: image/jpeg\r\n">}, "commit"=>"Create Listing"}
```

Here is my log after hitting back button the hitting submit again. Note the bank token created below but not above. See last row here.

```
 Parameters: {"utf8"=>"√", "authenticity_token"=>"WI5hCZpxIvpZ+Jq3ifwU+vVYKNoUd
 0RRCWTrYKmMKAA=", "listing"=>{"name"=>"test lister item", "description"=>"sdsf",
 "price"=>"22", "category"=>"Necklaces", "inventory"=>"4", "image"=>#<ActionDisp
 atch::Http::UploadedFile:0x3fdc7b8 @tempfile=#<Tempfile:C:/Users/amoosa/AppData/
 Local/Temp/RackMultipart20140809-3840-qetwl0>, @original_filename="mosaic-enamel
 -bracelet.jpg", @content_type="image/jpeg", @headers="Content-Disposition: form-
 data; name=\"listing[image]\"; filename=\"mosaic-enamel-bracelet.jpg\"\r\nConten
 t-Type: image/jpeg\r\n">}, "stripeToken"=>"btok_4YcZ4SdyNHG0Y0"}
```

My application.js file is as below. I removed all other js for now to test this.

```
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require turbolinks
//= require_tree .
//= require bootstrap
```

Any thoughts on what could be happening?

Comment: Are you using turbolinks?

Comment: Yes it's in the js above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Turbolinks**

Sounds like you've got an issue with `Turbolinks`

Turbolinks essentially loads new page `<body>` tags, leaving the `<head>` tag intact. The problem with this is that it will prevent your Javascript from being able to bind to the new elements in your `<body>` (as the [DOM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Document_Object_Model) has been refreshed)

The bottom line here is that it sounds to me like your JS isn't binding to the new `<body>` elements loaded by Turbolinks. To fix this, you can either use the [`jquery.turbolinks`](https://github.com/kossnocorp/jquery.turbolinks) gem, or the [`turbolinks event hooks`](https://github.com/rails/turbolinks#events)

I'll detail both for you:

---

[**jquery.turbolinks**](http://rubygems.org/gems/jquery-turbolinks)

This is the simplest fix for you:

```
#Gemfile
gem 'jquery-turbolinks', '~> 2.0.2'
```

This wraps your JS calls within the Turbolinks `page:load` event callback - essentially allowing your JS to become `turbolinks`-friendly. The beauty of this gem is that you don't need to do anything to make it work:

```
#app/assets/javascripts/application.js
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require jquery.turbolinks
//= require_tree .
//= require bootstrap
//= require turbolinks
```

--

**Event Hooks**

The *right* way to resolve the issue is to bind your events to the `Turbolinks` event hooks; allowing your JS to delegate correctly from elements present on the page at all times:

```
#app/assets/javascripts/application.js.coffee
your_function = ->
  $(your).functionality(here)

$(document).on("page:load ready", your_function)
```

Comment: Rich, I already have the turbolinks gem installed. I had this working earlier. It looks like I did something else along the way which caused this to stop firing. Is there anything else I can check?

Comment: Actually, i have `gem turbolinks` in gemfile and `require turbolinks` in application.js. What is the difference compared to `jquery-turbolinks` that you recommend?